# Gekko Optimization doesn't give me a unique answer although there is a unique answer for my model

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

my optimization model works but with different initial values for the main variable (Pre), it gives a different answer! not the optimal one! but this should have one answer.
I do not understand why!

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
   from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install','gekko'])

from gekko import GEKKO    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#define parameter
df=pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\....')
Pw=pd.DataFrame(df).values
eta = m.Const(value=0.6)
Pre=m.Var(lb=20, ub=30)
Pre.value=23


def f(Pw,Pre):
    Dplus=m.Var(value=0)
    Dminus=m.Var(value=0)
    for i in range(744):
       D=float(Pw[i])-Pre.value
       if D>=0:
          Dplus.value=Dplus.value+D*eta.value
       elif D<0:
          Dminus.value=Dminus.value+D
    return Dplus+Dminus

#constraint:
m.Equation(f(Pw,Pre)>=0)

#Objective:
m.Minimize(f(Pw,Pre))
```

#Set global options:
m.options.IMODE = 2 #steady state optimization

#Solve simulation:
m.solve()

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `.value` to build model equations because it only references the initial guess value, not the variable value. Use the `m.if3()` (preferred) or `m.if2()` functions to use conditional statements in the model. Here is an example of `m.if3()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = m.Param()
y = m.if3(p-4,p**2,p+1)

# solve with condition<0
p.value = 3
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value)

# solve with condition>=0
p.value = 5
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value)
```

An even better way to incorporate conditional statements is to use slack variables. It appears that your application is for energy storage where there is inefficiency in the storage process given by `eta`. Here is a [simple energy storage problem](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks) (see problem 4) where the loss from storage and retrieval is embedded in the optimization.

[image: energy storage]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,101)

g = m.FV(); g.STATUS = 1 # production
s = m.Var(1e-2, lb=0)    # storage inventory
store = m.Var()          # store energy rate
s_in = m.Var(lb=0)       # store slack variable
recover = m.Var()        # recover energy rate
s_out = m.Var(lb=0)         # recover slack variable
eta = 0.7
d = m.Param(-2*np.sin(2*np.pi*m.time)+10)
m.periodic(s)
m.Equations([g + recover/eta - store >= d,
             g - d == s_out - s_in,
             store == g - d + s_in,
             recover == d - g + s_out,
             s.dt() == store - recover/eta,
             store * recover <= 0])
m.Minimize(g)

m.options.SOLVER   = 1
m.options.IMODE    = 6
m.options.NODES    = 3
m.solve()

plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,d,'r-',label='Demand')
plt.plot(m.time,g,'b:',label='Prod')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.xlim([0,1])

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,s,'k-',label='Storage')
plt.plot(m.time,store,'g--', label='Store Rate')
plt.plot(m.time,recover,'b:', label='Recover Rate')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first figure is exactly what I'm looking for. Using this code, I changed the parameter "d" and gave the initial value and boundary for the variable "g". I then tested it to see if it worked for my model. However, it says that no feasible solution exists. By using a looping algorithm I was able to reach an optimum answer. So my model has a solution. What I have not yet figured out is how I shall go about applying gekko.

Comment: and also tried the new one with m.if3 but it doesn't work:    def f(Pw,Pre):                                                                                                                                                       
    D=[]
    t=1
    for i in range(3716):
        D.append(float(Pw[i])-Pre)   
    Dplus=m.Var(value=0)
    Dminus=m.Var(value=0)
    for i in range(3716):
        Dplus = m.if3(D[i] and D[i+1],((D[i]+D[i+1])*t/2)*eta,0)+Dplus
        Dminus = m.if3(D[i] and D[i+1],0,(D[i]+D[i+1])*t/2)+Dminus
    return Dplus+Dminus

Comment: Maybe try using slack variables instead of `m.if3()` functions as shown in the script above. If you have 3716 `m.if3()` functions then you also have 3716 binary variables. That can take a long time to solve because there are 2^3716 potential solutions.

Comment: First of all, John, I am more than thankful for your kind and quick answers. then, I used the slack variables as well in the same way you explained. but it says that there is no feasible solution although there is! I used the same code, just changed d parameter and time scale!

Comment: Try removing constraints until there is a feasible solution. Sometimes it helps to initialize with a feasible yet non-optimal solution as well. Additional strategies are discussed in this paper: https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/1688/ Safdarnejad, S.M., Hedengren, J.D., Lewis, N.R., Haseltine, E., Initialization Strategies for Optimization of Dynamic Systems, Computers and Chemical Engineering, 2015, Vol. 78, pp. 39-50, DOI: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2015.04.016.

Comment: I could handle it. Now it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: It has been a very long time since I posted and I hope you will see my comment. I would like to ask a question. Consider that I wish to solve exactly the example you described to me, but with full storage at the beginning. In other words, the inventory is not empty at the start of the model. What can I do to modify this model to meet this?

Comment: Could you ask another question about how to set an initial condition? I think it will help others too. It is m.Var(5) to change it from default.

Comment: but it is an initial guess not an initial fixed number for the first time.

Comment: See the documentation for `m.Var` where you can set `fixed_initial=False`: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html

Comment: Here is another question that is similar to your request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73324588/change-ode-initial-condition-to-meet-final-target/73324694#73324694

Comment: I checked it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have another question about this equation. I don't want "g" to be more than a specific number. But when I put the upper bound in [g = m.FV(ub=X)], the model doesn't work. Is there a way to do that? The results are more than I expected. What do I do?  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If `X` is a symbolic expression then use `m.Equation(g<X)`. If the addition of the constraint makes the problem infeasible then try adjusting the upper bound slowly until you find the point that makes it infeasible.

Comment: both methods make the problem unfeasible!

Comment: Try setting the upper bound higher (start with 1e10) and then lower it until the problem becomes infeasible. This will be the limit where the equations have a solution.