# What is the best approach to obtain initial values for a GEKKO optimisation problem?

Tags: python, gekko

I have a dynamic control problem with about 35 independent variables, many intermediate variables and a few equations,  mainly to enforce a sensible mass balance by limiting certain dependent variables (representing stream flows) to be positive.

Initially the variables were declared using the `m.Var()` constructor but I consequently upgraded them to MV an CV variables to capitalize on flexibility of tuning attributes such as `COST`, `DCOST`, etc. that these classes add.

I noticed that IPOPT (3.12) does not produce a solution (Error reported : `EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible`) when a set of variables are configured as `MV`'s, yet when one is instantiated as a `Var` a successful solution is returned.  I re-instantiated the variable as `MV` and systematically removed constraints to try and pinpoint the constraining equation.  I discovered that the set of initial conditions I provided for the independent variables constituted an infeasibility (it resulted in value of -0.02 on a stream that have a positive constraint on it).  Although `RTOL` can probably be used to solve the problem for this case, I do not think it is correct general approach. I have tried `COLDSTART=2` but do not know how to interpret the `presolve.txt` file generated.

Firstly, is there some standard functionality to assist with this situation or should one make sure the initial guesses represent a feasible solution.

Secondly, why would the inability to produce a successful solution only manifest when the variable is declared as an `MV` as opposed to the less decorated `Var`?

Answer (score 1):

The `m.Var()` creates an additional degree of freedom for the optimizer while `m.Param()` creates a quantity that is determined by the user. The `m.Var()` types can be upgraded to `m.SV()` as state variables or `m.CV()` as controlled variables. The `m.Param()` type is upgraded to `m.FV()` for fixed values or `m.MV()` for manipulated variables. If the `STATUS` parameter is turned on for those types then they also become degrees of freedom. More information on `FV`, `MV`, `SV`, and `CV` types is given in the [APMonitor documentation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/INFO) and [Gekko Documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html). The problem likely becomes feasible because of the additional degree of freedom. Try setting the `m.MV()` to an `m.SV()` to retain the degree of freedom from the `m.Var()` declaration.

Initial solutions are often easiest to obtain from a steady-state simulation. There are additional details in this paper:

[image: Initialization Strategies]

Here is a flowchart that I typically use:

[image: flowchart]

There are additional details in the paper on how `COLDSTART` options work. If the solver reports a successful solution, then there should be no constraint violations.

Comment: I have the MV STATUS as 1 so it would use it would add a degree of freedom (for each time step).  Is it possible that the reason for different behaviour is that an MV is not adjustable at time step  t0 but a Var() or CV() is adjustable (initialised) at t0 so effectively t0 gets and extra degree of freedom?

Comment: The initial condition is fixed for both `MV` and `CV` unless `fixed_initial=False` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73324588/change-ode-initial-condition-to-meet-final-target/73324694#73324694  One difference may be if `m.options.NODES>=3` with how the CV has the additional collocation equations: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation while the MV has either zero-order hold (ZOH) or first-order (linear) equations that determine the internal node(s).